# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at index "1", size "1" when I click on favorite icon

Tags: java, android

I have 1 image icon is favorite icon, have 2 status click and none click. When I click on favorite in Adapter at item position "0" is 1 product added in FavoriteList getted from ProductList, but when I click on favorite icon in Adapter at item position "1" is I'm getting the error:

"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at index "1", size "1" when I click on favorite". Guys can help me for this error ? Thanks

Some about of code:

```
itemHolder.imageView_fav_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numClick++;

            if (numClick % 2 != 0) { // isClicked
                itemHolder.imageView_fav_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_selected);

                MainActivity.yeuthichArrayList.add(new YeuThich(sanPham.getId(), sanPham.getTensp(),
                                sanPham.getHinhanhsp(), sanPham.getGiasp()));

                Log.v("numClick", String.valueOf(numClick));
            } else {
                itemHolder.imageView_fav_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_unselect);
                MainActivity.yeuthichArrayList.remove(i);
                YeuThichActivity.yeuThichAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                Log.v("numClick", String.valueOf(numClick));

            }

            if (numClick == 3) { // reset numclick = 1
                numClick -= 2;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception? Please provide stack trace if possible.

Also, the exception message says that you're trying to access 2nd element from an array of size 1. (Since arrays in Java are zero index based ie counting starts from index 0, accessing element at index 1 from an array of size 1  will result in exception.will result in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Comment: I'm getting the exeption at line: "MainActivity.yeuthichArrayList.remove(i);". I don't know why when click at next position in adapter it error

Comment: what is the value of i....and where is it come from?

Comment: Make sure you call `notifyDatasetChanged` or equivalent methods whenever you update the list / data source of the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

The indices of a size 1 array are {0}, if the array were size 5 the indices would be {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. The index of an array only goes up to its length - 1, you're trying to place an item at index 1 of an array that only has index 0.

Also giving the error's line numbers would be very helpful.

Comment: I do not understand why the error, but the error message is in the code: "MainActivity.yeuthichArrayList.remove(i)"

Comment: @KhanhLee It sounds like you're trying to remove something that doesn't exist, try removing `i - 1`?

Comment: remove i - 1 -> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

Comment: I thought that might happen, just check to make sure i is less than the length of the array. There's not much to go on based on the provided information. I don't even know where i is coming from.

Comment: i variable is position in onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) method.

Comment: That method isn't in the code you've supplied here. Not having that though I think your best bet is going to be just checking the value of i to make sure it's what you want.